# 3D printer giving me “too long extrusion prevented” error message when ever I try to print a model made in Blender

Tags: extruder, diy-3d-printer, calibration, reprap, blender

I am able to print files from Thingiverse just fine but having trouble printing anything designed in Blender. I get the error message “too long extrusion prevented” following which the print fails. I have tried different things to address the issue including: re-calculating E-steps, changing the extruder, trying a different slicer, adding a bed offset, downloading the latest version of Blender, and re-modeling the object. Nothing seems to work. Could someone please help me out so I could know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If this happens it's almost certainly a slicer configuration bug, either wrong start gcode or wrong retractiion settings. Can you clarify when it happens (immediately when starting print or later) and show the offending gcode?

Comment: Thanks, It seems to happen right about the fourth or fifth layer and i did use the same slicer to slice two files i downloaded from thingiverse and they printed fine. I have included a google drive link for the files. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WX24tydnv-WWFEU-TKXVji0Fvu6BjBqH?usp=drive_link

Comment: Can you be specific about a particular file and the exact Z height and ideally part of the print where the error occurs in it?

Comment: Every one of the files in the folder have refused to print. The .gcode are the sliced versions of the stl files. The problem seems to happen randomly after the second layer. In some attempts It has gone on to reach the fourth layer before failing. The issue mostly starts around the legs/wings.

Comment: It doesn't happen randomly but deterministically for a particular file. Rather than asking someone trying to help you to guess cominatorically which place it's failing in each file, pick a single file and report **exactly** where it fails in that file. Then myself or someone else can read the gcode at the exact point of failure and try to figure out what's going on for you.

Comment: It truly does occur randomly sir. But the important thing is I found the solution. And as you mentioned earlier it is indeed a slicer issue. So for anyone having challenges printing things made in blender try as many slicers as possible. Super slicer worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes 3D modeling software does not produce good-quality STL files outputs

You can clean those using the opensource software [MeshLab](https://www.meshlab.net/)

Then you open your file and go into **Filters** > **Cleaning and Repairing**; there you apply the merges, the duplicate removal, and the repair non-manifold.

When the file is not too damaged most of the slicers have mesh fixing options; in Cura, it is in the Mesh Fixes section. There are options for removing holes stitching, etc.

The symptom of long extrusion prevented is weird though as it means it is trying to make a line with more than 10 or 20 cm of filament which once extruded makes a few netters the first time I see that as a symptom of bad STL.

P.S. You might want to look at the arc segment setting (I do not know the proper name for Blender) in Blender for the cylinders as there are not a lot of segments and your holes are not rounds.